# Sum of data from a Specific Hour part for a Week - MS SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, datepart

In order to find the Sum of data(CallsAnswered in my case) for a Week but a specific Hours between 6 PM to 12 AM., I have below set of a query, but it is skipping one-day data in my sample data. Could you please validate my query and help me out me to find where I'm missing?

*Create Query:*

```
Create Table tblSingleBox (ScanDate DateTime, SkillTargetID Varchar(10), CallsAnswered int)
```

*Insert Query*

```
Insert into tblSingleBox 
Values ('2018-02-18 19:17:01', '10888', 32),
('2018-02-18 23:59:59', '10888', 01),
('2018-02-19 00:10:01', '10888', 15),
('2018-02-19 17:59:59', '10889', 12),
('2018-02-19 20:59:59', '10889', 90),
('2018-02-25 21:59:59', '10889', 40)
```

*Query:*

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,101)ScanDate,SkillTargetID, SUM(CallsAnswered)CallsAnswered
FROM    tblSingleBox (nolock)
WHERE    DATEPART(Hour, scandate) between 18 and 24
    and (scandate between '2018-02-18' and '2018-02-25')
GROUP BY    convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,101) ,SkillTargetID
order by convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,101)
```

*Expected Output:*

```
ScanDate    SkillTargetID   CallsAnswered
18-02-2018  10888   33
18-02-2018  10889   11
19-02-2018  10889   90
25-02-2018  10889   40
```

*Actual Output I'm getting:*

```
ScanDate    SkillTargetID   CallsAnswered
02/18/2018  10888   33
02/18/2018  10889   11
02/19/2018  10889   90
```

Comment: @Nisarg Thanks for noting this. I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scandate` has time in it and `2018-02-25 21:59:59` is greater than `2018-02-25` (which is treated as `2018-02-25 00:00:00` when compared to DATETIME).

So cast `scandate` to `DATE` (to cutoff time) or change

```
scandate between '2018-02-18' and '2018-02-25'
```

to

```
scandate >= '2018-02-18' and scandate < '2018-02-26'
```

Comment: Super Man. So If I put `scandate >= '2018-02-18' and scandate < '2018-02-26'` It won't count if we have data between '2018-02-18 18:00:00' and '2018-02-18 23:59:59'?

Comment: It will. If you don't need `2018-02-18` then you need to change `>=` to `>` same as for `2018-02-26`

Comment: Sorry actually i wrongly mentioned as 2018-02-18. If we have data between 2018-02-26 18:00:00 and 2018-02-26 23:59:59. Will this consider 26th data as well?

Comment: No, `scandate < '2018-02-26'` means  no `2018-02-26` even with time `00:00:000`. No matter whether you are comparing it to DATETIME or DATE data.

Comment: u really helped me :)